# How do I make a “directed” spark gap?

Tags: electron, arc

(Originally asked on engineering StackExchange, I was directed to ask it here)

For a project, I need to create a spark gap that only triggers when there is a conducting material between the 2 contacts. That wouldn't be a problem, normally, but in this specific case, the arc would have to close a distance that is larger than the distance between the poles. I provided an image for explaination.

[image]

I need a way to sort of direct the electric field in such a way that it basically follows that path and, when the conducting material is placed there, it would simply arc down to the next connector. Think of it as a wire leading to the material. But I have no idea how to create such an "air wire", or if it even is possible. I considered something akin to a cathode tube, the electrons here move in the form of a beam and don't "search" for their own path. However, this wouldn't work, as then we'd already have an electron flow, instead of it beginning to arc when the conducting material closes the spark gap. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Block the standard path with an insulator.

Comment: Way too general. There cannot be a bright line answer to this. You don't get to propose some abstract geometry and then expect nature to obey your abstraction in some reliable way. Doesn't happen. So you will need to provide more details. Lots more. Physics is useful. But not without deducing it into specific situations. What's the shape of the conducting material? Can you alter it? Can you rotate it? Can you charge it? Can you heat it? What distances are involved? Is the intervening material "air?" Etc. Etc. Etc.

Comment: if the conducting material is to be between the two contacts, then draw it as 'between', not off to one side, like JRE has

Comment: Make poles have pointy ends which point towards the general direction where the conducting material is likely to occur. Like a lightning rod. Pointy ends concentrate (?) Electric fields (?).  And what the top comment said about an insulator between poles. High voltage transmission lines have such spark gaps with intermediate insulators.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to get what you described is a set up like this sketch:

[image]

1. Distance "a" is longer than your arc can jump.
2. Distance "b" and "c" together are shorter than "a."
3. Your object must be conductive.
4. Your arc must be able to jump the distance "b" + "c".
5. Distance "b" + "c" + "d" can be pretty much any distance you like - but distance "b" + "c" must always be shorter than "a" and the arc must be able to jump the "b" + "c" distance.

The distances must always be measured between the points of closest approach